# Reading two text files and putting them into a two dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read two separate text files using a scanner and placing them into an 2D-array. One file contains a list of book titles and another file contains a list of author names. I want to match each line at the same location for both files but I am having difficulty figuring this out. The biggest issue is that I only know how to do this accessing one file and not two files at the same time. This is really confusing to me and any help would be much appreciated. So far I have this code:

```java
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    File file1 = new File("data/books.txt");
    File file2 = new File("data/names.txt");
    Scanner names = new Scanner(file1);
    Scanner titles = new Scanner(file2);
    int rows = names;
    int columns = titles;
    int [][] myArray = new int[rows][columns];
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            String[] line = sc.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
            for (int j=0; j<line.length; j++) {
                myArray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting `sc.hasNextLine()` if your scanners are called names and titles? U can start by changing that for example.

Comment: Very confusing, I tried to build an answer to guide you to a solution but ended up with a growing list of questions.  Why does the names scanner use the books file and the titles scanner use the names file?  Why does neither scanner get used to actually scan anything?  How have you declared integer values to be equal to scanner objects???  What is myArray supposed to represent?   From the question, I would guess it's pairings of books and authors, but its an integer array (unless all your books and authors are given numeric IDs).  Where did sc come from?

Comment: Pity comments are so short...  It is not my intention to just throw a list of faults at your work.  I am just confused.  If you can help clarify what is supposed to be going on here, I would be happy to help you build a solution which achieves that aim :)

Comment: Provide an example of the data that is contained within each of the Text Files.

Answer (score 0):

What it appears is that you have two data files with parallel related data whereas *line one* of **names.txt** is the author's name for the Book Title located on *line one* of the **books.txt** file and so on.

All that jargon you had thrown together in your code is an attempt to acquire the initialization length value for your 2D Array which is of course of the wrong data type  altogether (int[][]). It should be of type String[][]. I think what you are trying to achieve is something like what I provide in the method below. Read the code comments:

```
public static String[][] readTitleAuthorFiles(String bookTitlesFilePath, String authorsFilePath) {
    // Declare the 2D Array and initialize to null in case a problem arises.
    String[][] booksArray = null;  
    List<String> bookTitles = new ArrayList<>();  // List to hold titles from titles file.
    List<String> authorNames = new ArrayList<>(); // List to hold author names from names file.
    
    // Read in titles first.
    File file = new File(bookTitlesFilePath);
    try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(file)) {
        String line;
        while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
            line = reader.nextLine().trim();
            bookTitles.add(line);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        return null;
    }
    
    // Read in Authors
    file = new File(authorsFilePath);
    try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(file)) {
        String line;
        while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
            line = reader.nextLine().trim();
            authorNames.add(line);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        return null;
    }
    
    // The Lists (bookTitles and authorNames)are now filled. 
    // These two collections are to be considered parallel
    // whereas index 1 of one list is directly related to 
    // index 1 of the other list.
    
    // Initialize our String[][] booksArray.
    booksArray = new String[bookTitles.size()][2];
    
    // Fill the 2D booksArray[][] from the two Lists
    for (int i = 0; i < bookTitles.size(); i++) {
        booksArray[i][0] = bookTitles.get(i);
        booksArray[i][1] = authorNames.get(i);
    }
    
    // Return our created 2D String Array (booksArray[][]).
    return booksArray;  
}
```

To use this method:

```
// The 'books.txt' file must be provided first.
String[][] books = readTitleAuthorFiles("data/books.txt", "data/names.txt");
    
// Display the 2D String Array in console:
for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(books[i]).replaceAll("\\[\\]", ""));
}
```